# Sharepoint 2010 Creating Task and Sending E-Mail

Tags: sharepoint, email, task, outlook-2003

I install Sharepoint 2010 in our company server.

When I create a new task in Sharepoint 2010, I want to send another user an e-mail or automaticly import their outlook task part. Is there a setting on Sharepoint 2010 like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sharepoint designer you can create a workflow that triggers on the task creation an sends an email. Not sure if that is the simplest solution but it should work.